# Listening for changes in a mySQL database (with PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, push

Lets say I have a system, in which the operator opens a slot (which creates a new row in a mySQL DB) and then a QR code appears on screen. The user scans it with his iPhone, then presses 'approve', which changes one of the columns in the new row to  `true`.

How can I make it so when it does change to `true`, a message will pop up on the operator screen?

I thought of two ways that might be possibly done:

1. a change in the row can trigger something that will push a message to the operator's machine.
2. if the operator can go into a page, that will only load up when the row = `true`, but I can't figure out how to do that.

If you know how to do some of the stuff I listed above, or have a different idea, please share it, it will be highly appreciated :D

Comment: @8-bit mate just a heads up you will get more/better responses to your questions if you accept more answers as the accepted answer you have a 43% accepts rate which is...not good

Comment: just passing on what helped me when I started here, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an AJAX call. Make a php page that checks the database and returns a very simple yes/no response that can be read by javascript. Then, use ajax to query that on an interval (such as every 5 seconds) until the page returns a yes. After that, you can easily alert the user (the javascript alert() function would work, or you might want to code up something fancier).

Comment: Since someone just upvoted this, I will add a comment - There are lots of new technologies that can help with requirements like this. Since I wrote this answer, websockets have been through the RFC process & I have had some small opportunities to create notifications using them. I would highly recommend researching websockets if your looking into functionality such as this.

Answer (score 0):

**Easy solution:**
Just create a flag in your database `boolHasBeenShowed`. When someone presses approve you set the `boolHasBeenShowed` to true.

When the operator opens the admin page, check the database for all the records `WHERE boolHasBeenShowed = TRUE`. As soon as they have been showed, `UPDATE` the `boolHasBeenShowed = false`. That way you will only see the newly approved records.